# PHP Regex: Matching Contact Us Link

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am not sure why this isn't matching. But lets say there is a whole page of html and i want the Contact Us link, regardless of if the text in the link is "Contact us", "contact us", "Contact" etc.

Sample html:

```
<a href="contact.html">
    Contact Us
</a>
```

Here is the preg_match i am trying to use, although it isn't matching anything:

```
preg_match('/<a.*href="(.*)".*>.*contact.*<\/a>/is',$data,$matches);
```

Matches is just an empty array

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 0):

It's because . isn't matching new lines. Add the [multi-line modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (m) to the regex and it should work.

```php
preg_match('/<a.*href="(.*)".*>.*contact.*<\/a>/ism',$data,$matches);
```

Comment: hmm, i thought the /s modifier was for that

Comment: this seems to work on my example html, but the web page im trying to get the link from it's not

Comment: in fact really weird. if i take the html chunk from the page and put it into $data it matches fine, but with the whole page of html in $data it matches nothing

Comment: that's because your regex is to greedy.

Comment: that means a lot! what can i do to make it less greedy?

Comment: Greedy is a regex term that means it is capturing more then what you intended. Try the regex from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strict regex to ensure you match only valid `<a href="#"></a>` tags.

```
 $content = '<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>';
 $regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)contact(.*)<\/a>/siU";
 preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

If you want to scrape HTML pages, but do it without having to write long regex and then test them. Give the [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) library a try. It allows you to use CSS style selectors to extract data from HTML.

**EDIT:**

How to do the same thing with PHPQuery.

```
 phpQuery::newDocument('<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>');
 $links = pq('a:contains("Contact")');
```

Comment: nah this is not what i want. the contact link will be taken from many different web pages. so matching css won't work. otherwise i would of used xpath

Comment: PHPQuery uses CCS3 selectors which are very flexible. It can easily find what you need.

Comment: thanks, i will have a look at this today. Regex has always been one of the most difficult things in programing for me. The concept makes sense, but some times like this example it's a pain in the ass